# Convert the contents of a drop-down box and store them in a variable

Tags: javascript

This may seem easy to the experts out there,

But, how can I go about converting the contents of a drop down (select box) and store them into a comma separated var?

```
[DROP DOWN]
abdcef1
ghijklm2
nopqrs3
tuvwx4
yz0007
```

expected result:

```
var x = abdcef1,ghijklm2,nopqrs3,tuvwx4,yz0007
```

Much thanks and appreciation for all your help and support.

Cheers,

Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
<script>
function getSelectedValues() {
  var result = "";
  var mysel = document.getElementById("myselect");

  for (var i = 0; i < mysel.options.length ; i++) {
    result = result + mysel.options[i].text + ",";
  }

  result = result.substring(0,result.length-1);

  return result;
}</script>
```

where

```
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="abdcef1">abdcef1</option>
  <option value="ghijklm2">ghijklm2</option>
  <option value="nopqrs3">nopqrs3</option>
  <option value="tuvwx4">tuvwx4</option>
  <option value="yz0007">yz0007</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Works flawlessly. Is there anyway to get rid of the last comma on the end though?

Comment: Thanks for editing. Almost promising though. Getting an error Object Expected. with that result = code.

Comment: double closing paranthesis after `length-1`... please try it!

Comment: After a little head scratching, I removed the last ")" bracket and it worked! Genious! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery:

```
var options = [];
$('select#dropdown option').each(function(){
  options.push($(this).val());
});
options.join(", ");
```